# Twig: Access to a specific array field

Tags: php, twig, silex

I have a database table that contain 5 fields.

```
Table(id,A,B,C,D,E); // the Id is Auto_increment.
```

In it I have 2 lines , then I execute

```
$recup=$app['db']->executeQuery("SELECT * FROM postit");
$result = $recup->fetchAll();
```

to get all data.

In return I send ( I'm using Silex framework )

```
return $app['twig']->render('accueil.twig',array('postits'=>$result));
```

Now in Twig I would like get ,for example, `C field` of the second line.
 I tried

```
{% for  user  in postits%}

    {%for key,  useruser in user %}
        {{useruser}}
    {%endfor%}
{%endfor%}
```

It prints

```
1 title hugo 602 186 texttext 2 title2 hugo2 188 132 texttxet2
```

I would for exemple juste print `1` or `hugo` etc..

Answer (score 2):

You can access [arrays fields](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html) in `twig` just like you access them in `php`:

```
{% for user in postits %}
   Using square brackets: {{ user['A'] }}<br />
   Using dot: {{ user.id }}<br />
{%endfor%}
```

Comment: And out of loop how can I access to `hugo2`

Comment: How you mean outside the loop? In this case it would be sthing like `{{ postits[1]['A] }}`